# Error google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que contiene un mapa, usando la google maps api v2, lo que hace el mapa es mostrarte tu ubicación y el punto mas cercano a ti, buscando en una serie de puntos previamente guardados.

El problema es que he probado en distintos dispositivos y funciona perfectamente en todos, excepto en los android 6.0, en los cuales simplemente se carga el mapa sin señalar ubicación ni nada y no da ningún tipo de error.

Aquí está el código.

```
public class TiendaCercana extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    eventMarkerMap = new HashMap<Marker, EventInfo>();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa_layout);

    mapFragment = new MainMapFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.map, mapFragment);

    ft.commit();
}

  @Override

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setUpEventSpots();
}

 private void setUpEventSpots() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
}

 LocationManager mLocationManager;


private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        }
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
 }
}
```

Y este es el fragment del mapa

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainMapFragment extends MapFragment {

public Marker placeMarker(EventInfo eventInfo) {

    Marker m  = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(eventInfo.getLatLong())
            .title(eventInfo.getNomCom()));
    return m;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Llama el método en `onStart()` el siguente méttodo:

```
 private void setUpEventSpots() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
}
```

este método es el que revisa los permisos en Android 6.0 y  activa el mapa en caso de que se tengan habilitados :

```
mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Perdón, se me debió olvidar al copiar el código, se llama en el onStart().

Comment: Ok entonces al asegurar que se tienen llama ahora: mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Solicita los permisos en `onStart`, ya que este se esta llamando a ejecutar antes de `getLastKnownLocation`, por lo que el codigo:

```
mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);

myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
```

nunca se esta ejecuntando por que si no tienes los permisos haces un return.

eh implementa `onRequestPermissionsResult`, para en caso de que el usuario si acepte el permiso actives la ubicacion con:

```
mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
```